# Arduino with adafruit RGBLCDShield Buttons weird behavior

Tags: c, button, arduino, adafruit, ldc

I have the Arduino uno with rgb lcd shield. there is a very weird behavior with the buttons in one specific function.

The function is called yes/no. It displays a message on the screen (working) the user can select answer yes/no with the buttons up/down/left/right and approve the answer by pressing select button.

The function is as follows:

```
bool yesno(String message)
{
  //Serial.println("asking yesno question " + message);
  bool answer = false;
  bool answerSelected = false;
  setColor('r');
  setText(message+'?', "no");
  while (!answerSelected)
  {
    uint8_t buttons = lcd.readButtons();
    if (buttons){
      if (buttons &(BUTTON_UP || BUTTON_DOWN || BUTTON_RIGHT || BUTTON_LEFT)) {
        if (answer) {
          answer = false;
          setColor('r');
          setText(message+'?', "no");
          Serial.println(answer);
        }
        else {
         answer = true;
         setColor('g');
         setText(message+'?', "yes");
         Serial.println(answer);
        }
      }
      else if (buttons & BUTTON_SELECT) {
        setColor('w');
        answerSelected = true;
        Serial.println("selected ");
        Serial.println(answer);
        return answer;
      }
    }
    delay(50);
  }
}
```

for some reason, when pressing left/right/up/down, nothing happens. When pressing select, instead it executes function up/down/left/right

using `if (buttons &&(BUTTON_UP || BUTTON_DOWN || BUTTON_RIGHT || BUTTON_LEFT))` instead, the buttons left/right/up/down work as intended but the button select still acts as the other buttons

similar code for a menu works as intended:

```
void InitializeMenu()
{
  // initialize
  Serial.println("entering menu");
  setColor('w');
  while (!exitMenu)
  {
    if (menuItem != selectedItem)
    {
      Serial.println("switching menu to: "+menuItems[menuItem]);
      setText("Menue", menuItems[menuItem]);
      selectedItem = menuItem;
    }
    uint8_t buttons = lcd.readButtons();
    if (buttons & BUTTON_UP) {
      menuItem--;
      Serial.println("menu up");
      Serial.println(menuItem);
      Serial.println(menuSize);
      if (menuItem < 0) 
      {
        menuItem = menuSize;
        Serial.println("start of menu going to end");
      } 
    }
    if (buttons & BUTTON_DOWN) {
      menuItem++;
      Serial.println("menu down");
      Serial.println(menuItem);
      Serial.println(menuSize);
      if (menuItem > menuSize) {
        menuItem = 0;
        Serial.println("end of menu going to start");
       }
     }
     if (buttons & BUTTON_SELECT) {
      Serial.println("enter");
       if (menuItem == menuSize) exitMenu = true;
     }
     delay(50);
  }
}
```

I want to keep the code as short and simple as possible due to very limited space on the arduino uno.

Answer (score 0):

```
BUTTON_UP || BUTTON_DOWN || BUTTON_RIGHT || BUTTON_LEFT
```

doesn't do what you expect it to do. `||` is *logical* `or`, and the entire expression evaluates to `true`. To get a bitmask, change it to *bitwise* `or` (`|`):

```
BUTTON_UP | BUTTON_DOWN | BUTTON_RIGHT | BUTTON_LEFT
```